# Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object

Tags: laravel

**controller**

```
public function update_homepage(){
    $contents = DB::table('posts')->select('post_title','post_excerpt')
                                  ->latest()
                                  ->first();
    return view('index', ['contents' => $contents]);
}
```

**index view**

```
 @foreach ($contents as $details)
      <h4>{{$details->post_title}}</h4>
 @endforeach
```

I get an error:

> Trying to get property 'post_excerpt' of non-object

Comment: have you spelt post_excerpt wrong anywhere else?

Comment: are you getting data in `dd` ??

Comment: yes ! {#224 ▼
  +"post_title": "hello man"
  +"post_excerpt": "how are you"
}

Comment: try with `get()` method instead of `first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving a single record with `first()`, so the variable `$contents` is not a collection of records but a single records.

So when you cycle over contents with foreach you are not cycling over a collection of objects.

Try to change the view like that:

```
<h4>{{$contents->post_title}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `\DB::table()->first()`, it gives you a single `stdClass` object and not an array/iterator.

So you do not need to do foreach in blade, you can directly access `{{ $contents->post_title }}`

If you to `\DB::table()->get()`, it will give you an array which contain all rows represented as `stdClass` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object

This error will show when you the object is empty even you are trying to get the property from the empty object. So please make sure the array have objects also the post title property is in every objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `first()` method will give only the first matching record, So you will get only a single object. Use `get()` instead of first to get all matching records as

```
public function update_homepage(){
    $contents = DB::table('posts')->select('post_title','post_excerpt')
                              ->latest()
                              ->get();
    return view('index', ['contents' => $contents]);
}
```

Then iterate over your collection result as

```
@foreach ($contents as $details)
  <h4>{{$details->post_title}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Function**

```
public function update_homepage()
{

    $selectArray  = ['post_title','post_excerpt'];

    $tableName = 'posts';

    $postContentsAll = DB::table($tableName)
                            ->select($selectArray)
                            ->latest()
                            ->get();

    $postContentsFirst = DB::table($tableName)
                            ->select($selectArray)
                            ->latest()
                            ->first();

     dd($postContentsAll,$postContentsFirst);

    $viewShareVars = ['postContentsAll','postContentsFirst'];

    return view('index', compact($viewShareVars));

}
```

**Explanation**

> first() METHOD

if you are using `first()` method it will return the **OBJECT** not the **COLLECTION**

so in the view you cannot `iterate` by `foreach`

just do this  `{{ $postContentsFirst->post_title}}`

> get() METHOD

if you are using `get()` method it will return the **COLLECTION**

so in the view you can `iterate` by `foreach`

just do this

```
@foreach($postContentsAll as $item)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $loop->post_title }}</td> 
   <td>{{ $item->post_excerpt }}</td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**BUT STILL SOME SITUATION**

> Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object

reason

You are **SELECTING** only

`'post_title','post_excerpt'`

from the table `posts`  if you try to access other fileds you may get

> **Trying to get property**

OR

> **Undefined property: stdClass::$propertyName**

If you are using my function, don't forget to remove:

```
dd($postContentsAll,$postContentsFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  <h4>{{$contents ->post_title}}</h4>
```

No need to use loop in your case